# How to save a PictureBox Image in DB

Tags: vb.net

when i try to capture an image to my webcam in VB.NET using Emgu and copy it into another PictureBox in another Form with this code `Form23.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(captureImageBox.Image)` and try to save it in my database, it doesn't save and an error appears like this `Empty path name is not legal` but the picture is there and copied from the webcam PictureBox.

this is my code in saving the image in database:

```
Dim a As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

SQL = "UPDATE candidate SET photo='" photo=@photo WHERE idn='" & cd & "'"
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@photo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@photo").Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)

       With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = SQL
            .Connection = sConnection
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but if i save an image from `OpenFileDialog` it saves. why can't it be?hmm
is there a problem in my code in copying the Image from PictureBox to another?

**UPDATE**

tried this but it doesn't work either:

Replaced this:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@photo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@photo").Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)

       With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = SQL
            .Connection = sConnection
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

with this one:

```
Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
Dim data As Byte() = MS.GetBuffer()
Dim p As New MySqlParameter("@photo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob)
p.Value = data
cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@cd", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cd
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: The code you’ve posted doesn’t compile. Yo must be doing something different.

Comment: the text doesnt match the code.  are you trying to save file bytes (code) or `PictureBox1.Image` (question)?  and if you are instancing your forms now, `Form23...` would be wrong.

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the ReadAllBytes line and look at the value of a.FileName

Comment: `""` is this the value that you're talking about? it shows when i point at it.

Comment: @Plutonix im trying to save `PictureBox1.Image`.

Comment: This will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: fiddling with openFileDialog wont save the Image displayed in the picbox.  did you also save the cam capture to file as well as copy the image to the PicBox?

Comment: no, it just copied directly from cam picturebox. is that the only way to achieve what i wanted it to do?

Comment: well then, what is the purpose of the file dialog if there is not also a disk copy of the image?

Comment: does that mean the image cannot be saved if it's only in the PictureBox? and is not opened by the file dialog?

Comment: no, it means I, for one, cant figure out which problem to solve.  Saving a PB Image does not need an OpenFileDialog, so I am wondering what role it plays if you want **Cam -> Frm23.PB.Image -> db**  if `it just copied directly from cam picturebox` then why is there a File Dialog

Comment: because i have a Form that contains a Button named Browse Image and another Button named Cam Image and a PB, i was trying to save the image that came from the cam PictureBox.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still lost and now we are out of space - it sounds like you have 2 different functions commingled.  Saving from PB to DB is one thing; saving or reading from a file is another which seems to have creeped in only in the comments.  If you edit the Question to add some clarity, I'll try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat: **I have no idea what role the FileDialog plays in all this.  Saving an image from a PictureBox to a database does not involve a File or a FileDialog.**  This address the Title question, not the updates where files and dialogs creep in.

First, consider **not** storing an image, but the name of an archived copy of the filename.  You can mangle these as in `<id>_<orgfilename>.<ext>` if you want to embed the ID to the disk file.

To save a picturebox image, it needs to be converted to as byte array.  Net includes a type converter for that:

```
Dim imgData As Byte()         ' storage for the img bytes

Dim cvt As New ImageConverter
imgData = CType(cvt.ConvertTo(myImage, GetType(Byte())), Byte())
```

It works (usually), but it also does boxing back and forth from Object (the CType) and issues with the ImageFormat it selects bug me.  Doing it yourself is very simple:

```
' this is easily used from a class or converted to an extension
Public Shared Function ImgToByteArray(img As Image, imgFormat As ImageFormat) As Byte()
    Dim tmpData As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        img.Save(ms, imgFormat)

        tmpData = ms.ToArray
    End Using              ' dispose of memstream
    Return tmpData
End Function
```

This is pretty much what the TypeConverter does without the boxing, but the code controls the format.  Then save the byte array to the db:

```
Dim imgData As Byte()         ' storage for the img bytes
imgData = ImgToByteArray(PictureBox1.Image, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

...
sqlCommand.Parameters("@photo").Value = imgData
```

If you want a more generic procedure to save from file *or* picturebox, create a procedure which accepts a byte array as a param.  The button click for Save PictureBoxImage can convert the image to byte array and pass it, as can the other button working from a file:

```
Function SaveRecord(ingData As Byte(),...other params...) As Boolean
```

Note: Do not use GetBuffer.  See [MSDN MemoryStream.GetBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx):

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. 
>    For example, if the string "test" is written into the MemoryStream 
>    object, the length of the buffer returned from GetBuffer 
>    is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused. ...

On a 968,012 byte file, `.ToArray` returns the proper size, `GetBuffer` returns 1,719,296 with all elements after 968012 being Null.

---

With just a little work you can create a class of image helpers:

```
Public Class myImaging

    ' image to byte array from file name
    Public Shared Function ImgToByteArray(imgFile As String, 
                imgFormat As ImageFormat) As Byte()
       ...

    ' the one above
    Public Shared Function ImgToByteArray(img As Image, 
           imgFormat As ImageFormat) As Byte()
       ...

    ' going the other way Bytes() --> Image
    Public Shared Function ImgFromByteArray(b As Byte()) As Image
       ...

    ' shrink img and scale it
    Public Shared Function ImgToThumb(img As Image, maxSize As Size) As Image

End Class
```

Then it is just: `imgData = myImaging.ImgToByteArray(picturebox84.Image)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
'...

SQL = "UPDATE candidate SET photo= @photo WHERE idn= @cd"
Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand(SQL, sConnection)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@photo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@cd", MySqlDbtype.Int32).Value = cd

sConnection.Open()
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: still error appears `Empty path name is not legal` and it points here `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@photo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)` , i know it reads the file that opened by the `OpenFileDialog` but i don't know what to put here, could you help me please?

Comment: It says "Empty path name". Somehow a.Filename does not have a value.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer!

```
Dim cn As New MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root")
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE candidate SET cpos=@cpos, cparty=@cparty, candidacy='Filed', photo=@photo WHERE idn=@cd"
        Dim sqlcom As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn)
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
        Dim p As New MySqlParameter("@photo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob)
        p.Value = data
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add(p)
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpos", ComboBox1.Text)
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cparty", TextBox1.Text)
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@cd", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cd
        cn.Open()
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: you need to close and dispose of your memstream.  Use a `Using` block...and do not use `GetBuffer`

Comment: is it okay to use `ms.Close`? i don't know how to use `Using` what should i use with `GetBuffer`?

Comment: the answer is in...well the answer ;)